# Docker compose-Mount volume on a few containers AND the host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Im trying to share data between a few containers and the host using docker-compose. I have a docker-compose.yml file that looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  base:
    container_name: base
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: BaseDockerfile
    volumes:
      - dependencies:/volumes/dependencies
  romee:
    container_name: romee
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: RomeeDockerfile
    environment:
      - PYTHONPATH=/volumes/base_dependencies/
    volumes:
      - dependencies:/volumes/base_dependencies   

volumes:
    dependencies:
```

Now the volume "dependencies" is shared successfully between the containers, but I want to also share it with the host. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is equivalent to how to specify a path of a named volume:

Solution:

```
volumes:
  dependencies:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/abs/path/to/dependencies'
```

EDIT

The complete flow would be like,

Image: Dependency generator, at build time (docker build), generate dependency to /temp, then at run time (docker run / docker-compose up), `cp -pr /temp /dependencies`, after that it can exit 0.

Comment: Can you explain the order that the mounting is happening? for example, if I already have that directory on the server, will it override the containers data?

Comment: the host file will override the container data, this is desirable or not depending on how you share the dependency. How do you create them in the first place?

Comment: I wantto have one container creating the dependencies when on build and then other containers using them from the volume. I wanted to also be able to have access to that volume from the host